# MapboxGL extruding lines/circles

Tags: javascript, mapbox, visualization, geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to implement a LineString extrusion depending on timestamp. As mentioned on [github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-style-spec/issues/456) it is supposed to be implemented, but it isn't. It is supposed to look something like the screenshot below. [image]

So far I could find out that it is possible to use extrusion for polygons but then i would have to somehow create polygons from my LineStrings and circles. Is there another way to implement this? My plan is to show human movement in association with there timestamps (smallest z-axis heigth/altitude would represent the oldest timestamp).

Maybe there is another framework where this is possible but so far i m very pleased with MapboxGl JS. Thanks for anyhelp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only extrude polygon. You could use turf buffer to create polygon features from your linestring segments.

Comment: OK thanks! So I will have todo that. Are you aware of another framework/lib which can do my use case?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I ended up using fill-extrusion. I created Polygons between my geo points and extruded the or as mention it works perfectly with turf as well.